# Typescript spread operator for type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a type which gets a function type as a generic parameter and returns a function type which is the same as the input function type except it has one more argument at the end:

```js
  type AugmentParam<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, ExtraParam> = F extends (
    ...args: infer Args
  ) => infer R
    ? (
        ...args: [
          ...Args,
          ExtraParam
        ]
      ) => R
    : never
```

An example of the usage:

```
type F = (x: number) => boolean
type F2 = AugmentParam<F, string> // (x: number, arg2: string) => boolean
```

`...Args` seems not working, however if I change it to something like this it works:

```js
  type AugmentParam<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, ExtraParam> = F extends (
    ...args: infer Args
  ) => infer R
    ? (
        ...args: [
          Args[0],
          Args[1] /* Spread doesn't work here, so it doesn't work for arbitrary number of arguments :( */,
          ExtraParam
        ]
      ) => R
    : never
```

But it only works for a specific number of arguments and I need to define one such type for each n-ary function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript can fairly easily represent *prepending* a type onto a tuple type, called `Cons<H, T>` like this:

```
type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never

type ConsTest = Cons<1, [2, 3, 4]>;
// type ConsTest = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can use this definition along with conditional mapped tuple types to produce a `Push<T, V>` to *append* a type onto the end of a tuple:

```
type Push<T extends readonly any[], V> = Cons<any, T> extends infer A ?
    { [K in keyof A]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : V } : never

type PushTest = Push<[1, 2, 3], 4>;
// type PushTest = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but this definition of `Push` is fragile.  If the `T` tuple has [optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types), or if it comes from the parameter list of a function, you'll notice that the compiler "shifts" the optional markers and parameter names one element to the right:

```
type Hmm = (...args: Push<Parameters<(optStrParam?: string) => void>, number>) => void;
// type Hmm = (h: string | undefined, optStrParam?: number) => void
```

Parameter names are not really part of the type so while it's annoying it's not affecting the actual type.  Appending an argument *after* an optional one is... strange, so I'm not sure what the right behavior there.  Not sure if these are dealbreakers for you, but be warned.

Anyway your `AugmentParam` would look like:

```
type AugmentParam<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, ExtraParam> =
    (...args: Extract<Push<Parameters<F>, ExtraParam>, readonly any[]>)
        => ReturnType<F>
```

and it works (with the earlier caveats):

```
type F = (x: number) => boolean

type F2 = AugmentParam<F, string>
// type F2 = (h: number, x: string) => boolean

type F3 = AugmentParam<F2, boolean>
// type F3 = (h: number, h: string, x: boolean) => boolean
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM4B4ASAaKAVKEAewECAJklAE4QCGJiANiFNQiANoC6AfFALwCwAKCgioACjEALAFxRMUAHRLgs7AEo+PAG5wAliQ0EipchKUKKs3QgBmEClABKG3tr0GoAfidRZCCFr2QkKgkLCISNgQSMB84cgoAIxYbABMWADMWAAs3ADcQgD0hVCh0PDIUTFxbMlQ6VBZULnBgmVQAAoArkiSKLhGxGSUNHQIjMysnFgAajy88agsIFjYPIMmUNZ2DgCCXkKiUADeUGwA0lsIUADWECBwNlC7HLKXG8N3D0+43tgXHF8UBmUAAvkD-IEKK12t1elVYgs4X1algGhkODkuAVBMVSuBoMiETU6uichwYQS5ABbalxMTmagUADmSFkyJQHSZ1GpECIFFQYjgYGAAGVgBQuRQeZ5ZDEKNZmS43PouFgEF1qQAjexcZVQHT6HF49poWn0mRQeWKqAAHygXVIEBs1ggJCwwrFEqlMr8mp1FH1hpIlLCuy6zN5CGAPupKAAYnhCENTIyWWzJuwOPrllgAKKEaWx+aHUQMpRM1myAsS6gAY2AnJ6fVjfPsqHjaqgNaL3OpXaotAYTGWnD1paOIlcTj5XQoCGwBITXFD0ETCzE+D92vs+q1cDg9BoCFXUHjqTi4cjxBjfYTWGtCGZK9xJXa54t24DWC3Volir3A8jxYU94wyS8IyjW9pTjc8sH3Q9jxfE0qTAz8oA1HcKCwS1H2ZH9ZAQ4CEEAxCWCAA)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems the "shift" issue did matter for my case.
I was trying to use it with this type:
`(text: string, html: string|undefined, editorState: EditorState) => DraftHandleValue`
I'm defining a type like this: `AugmentParam<EditorProps['handleKeyCommand'], PluginFunctions>` but it seems it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough information for me to help.  Can you represent your issue as a [mcve]?