# TypeScript spread operator transform boolean to true | false when type compute

Tags: typescript

I'm taking type-challenge exercise with the easy part, implement the type version of Unshift.(https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/tree/master/questions/3060-easy-unshift)
Here is my code:

```
type Unshift<T extends unknown[], U> = U extends unknown[]
  ? [...U, ...T]
  : [U, ...T]
```

the problem is with boolean type:

```
type Res = Unshift<['1', 2, '3'], boolean>
// expected: [boolean,'1',2,'3']
// actual: [false,'1',2,'3'] | [true,'1',2,'3']
```

I don't know why is that and how to get expected result.
BTW, I got a pretty similar solution from another answer([Typescript spread operator for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713097/typescript-spread-operator-for-type)),

```
type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never
```

is it a trick that should be rote?

Comment: my guess is that this happens because boolean is handled like a union type, if you do something like this `type Res = Unshift<['1', 2, '3'], "a" | "b">` you get the same kind of result. EDIT: look at this: https://tsplay.dev/mZrx9m i think this has to do with the compiler trying to do discriminated unions

Comment: While an odd presentation, is `[false,'1',2,'3'] | [true,'1',2,'3']` different from `[boolean,'1',2,'3']` in any meaningful way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a union result type is that `boolean` is a union (`true` | `false`) and conditional types distribute over union types ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)). Because of this, `Unshift<['1', 2, '3'], boolean>` evaluates to `Unshift<['1', 2, '3'], true> | Unshift<['1', 2, '3'], false>`.

You can prevent it from happening by surrounding both sides of the `extends` condition with square brackets:

```
type Unshift<T extends unknown[], U> = [U] extends [unknown[]]
  ? [...U, ...T]
  : [U, ...T]

type Res = Unshift<['1', 2, '3'], boolean>
// type Res = [boolean, "1", 2, "3"]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgZwBYEsBmwA8AVKEAewEcAJglAK5wDWcA9gO5wDaAugDSwB8UAvFMxis8hYmQFVajFq1YBYAFBQoAfgEA6TTE6b12eUqgAuAdqi79ixaEhQAShHL94ydFmYByAIwfOAJk4PAGYPDigAIzo6ABsIAEM4LkUAemTlKAA9FUUgA)