# typescript mimic spread operator on typescript type

Tags: typescript

I want to mimic the behavior of the spread operator on types.
so for example `type tt = {...{t1:number},t2:number}` => `type tt = {t1:number,t2:number}`

**Goal**: reuse `t` `t={t1:any; t2:any}` on  `type tt = { t1:any; t2:any; specific:{t1:any; t2:any} }`, preferably like how `{ ...t; specific:t }` could have worked (in reality it is much more complex type)

possible solutions:

- `type tt = { t1:any; t2:any; specific:tt };` - works but nested is allowed unintentionally(`tt.specific.t1` is wanted but `tt.specific.t1.specfic` is not).
- another option that does not work.

  ```
  type t = { t1: any; t2: any;}
  type tt = { [key in keyof t]: t[key], specific: tt };
  //                                  ^ this is not allowed when {[...]:...} is used
  ```

[Typescript spread operator for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713097/typescript-spread-operator-for-type) is not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) to achieve the result you want

```js
type t = { t1: any; t2: any;}

type tt = t & { specific?: tt };
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBMULxQN4wIwC4oEMB2IDcMATBjvgL4CwAUNaJDLArAGRJQDOkAxgJYBmPLgH4MwWGTzVqXAPbZ2sTKMZtg6KAHJgEBRoA0RDFp3B9Hbv0EZkajCgPBiUQlDKvJVIA) is the link to TS Playground with the example

Answer (score 1):

Along side what @dzianis wrote, which is a very good solution you could also do something like this:

```
type tt = {
 t1: number
 t2: number
}

type Spread <T1, T2> = {
    [Property in keyof T1]: T1[Property]
} & T2

let combined: Spread<tt, {t3: boolean}> = {
    t1: 23,
    t2: 423,
    t3: false
}
```

This has little value on its own (it's just a more convoluted Intersection Types) but gives you more options in the future. You could be removing readonly from some types or exclude some of the keys, or even renaming them.

A playground can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMxQvFA3gKBgRgFxQHYFcBbAIwgCc1gAmbfYslAXxRVEigGUxSIBDAEygAeACroANFGGUAfAmRooigNoAFUgHtIpUFACWOKAGsIIdQDNJ6ALrZRqjVtBXGUAGSTKzADYQ4AY3VifQg+bE5ufkFYCSRgAGZsInV1Hx4cBllEVEVFYCwoSjixBVzqKAAWQuKcmASoMx4vAGcIRiA)

Comment: I actually thought about this but I don't like it since the type it can become not intuitive at all

Answer (score 0):

taking @Radu solution, adding a little tweak for a better type hint in the IDE and replacing the order of generics (so supplying spread<t1,t2> will look like spread t1 into t2)

```
// expands object types one level deep
export type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
//
type Spread<T1, T2> = Expand<
  {
    [Property in keyof T2]: T2[Property];
  } & T1
>;

type Handle = { style: React.CSSProperties; props: any; createEventHandlers: any};
type HandleNames= 'left'|'right'


// type is spreaded and more intuitive 
type HandleType = Spread<{ specific: { [key in HandleNames]: Handle } }, Handle>;
```

[ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMA8AcEMDsAmBnUB7ARgK3AYwC6j4Ce04qa84oANuAG7g2iLjjQBQU0aAToSTKgAojASIAPABUAfKAC8oKREj5wSVAEt4AM3C9QAeVAB+UAG9QAbQDSobaADW4Ymh1GAugC4jtj6ABfUB8qRl4Abg4QDkFqAGVoXnBYSSkARgAaJQAmOUVROCQJDlALEtLrAAVeNDJ+Ynt4Jxc3HO8cq2ra-RIPSNKggDIlNI4ZSJjSagAJcToFC1BkEjofACVkggA6AGE4uK66-E1ycNBE2uQfBGIz3CTYNWFGeHxZpDpeK9AbgMjY0DvRB0ABysAAtuRFAByOg6fDQgA+0N4mgA5gALBEcHGTIRAuhSKYLBIPSSWZBkXCaHSaXA+SxWZwNBwE8BgyHIdpswKBLJs8YcIA)